# Apply multiple filters to retrieve ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli

> **What syntax is required in the below command in order to apply two filters with AND joining the two filter parameters so that both filters must be applied?**

The following command lists the private IP addresses of all instances that have a specific tag:

```
$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2  
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress"  
  --filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=myName"  
  --output=text
```

But when I add a second filter to retrieve only the running instances,  the first filter is ignored and too many results are returned by the following:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" 
  --filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=myName","Name=instance-state-code,Values=16"  
  --output=text
```

What should the command be instead?

Comment: The real answer to this question, in case anyone else finds this:

Filters can be chained by repeating the command line option, e.g.:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag-key,Values=Tag1" --filters "Name=tag-key,Values=Tag2"`

(They are chained with an implicit `AND` operator)

Comment: This didn't work for me.  the solution I found was - aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=is-public,Values=true" "Name=owner-alias,Values=amazon" "Name=platform,Values=Windows" "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" 
( Link here - https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/commit/dff35d2cfd73f66cb58d20ba33c82e8a213788db)

Comment: @AlexB Filters will only be interpreted as an AND if there is a space in the middle: `--filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=myName" "Name=instance-state-code,Values=16"`. Incidentally, this seems to be the only way to combine filters without having to specify JSON. The format above doesn't seem valid.

Comment: For those looking for valid answer:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped Name=instance-type,Values=t2.micro`

as written at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html

To sum up: Do not use quotes at all to combine filters, first specify `--filters` option, put space afterwards and then space-separated `Name=xyz,Values=abc` pairs